# Minimizing disk usage with parallel calls to GCC

Tags: disk, gcc, tmpfs, write, haskell

I am experimenting with testing GCC in parallel. My setup will run 96 tests before giving me the test report.

If I run these tests sequentially it will invoke GCC once, run the executable, gather diagnostics and then repeat. However, when I try to run these tests in parallel the call to GCC takes much more time.

My profiler tells me that (when averaged over the 96 tests) the calls to GCC account for 2% of total execution time when running the 96 tests in sequence. My machine has 8 cores, and when I run the same profiler over my program, but with 8 available threads (12 tests on each thread), the calls to GCC account for 12% of the total time.

I theorized that perhaps the OS in this case is a shared resource, and tried to tell GCC to output the executable to a tmpfs location, but that only got me down to 11% of total time spent there. Can anyone help guide me a bit here? I am not too familiar with how the file system and IO writes work on Linux (Ubuntu 20).

I don't think my testing code is necessarily erroneous, but I'll include it anyway. It is written in Haskell. This is the function that takes 2% of all time when the tests are run sequentially, but (now) 11% when the tests are run in parallel on 8 threads (I do have 8 available cores).

```haskell
create_test_executable :: String -> State -> String -> IO ()
create_test_executable p s path = do -- p = the c program, s = unused here, path = where to write executable
    let process = proc "gcc" ["-xc", "-"]
    x@(Just sin, Just sout, Just serr, _) <-
        createProcess process { std_in  = CreatePipe
                              , std_err = CreatePipe
                              , std_out = CreatePipe
                              , cwd     = Just path
                              }
    hPutStr sin p
    hFlush sin
    hClose sin
    o <- hGetContents sout
    if o == "" then return () else return () -- force read from output pipe
    cleanupProcess x
```

To clarify: My suspicion is that GCC will write the executable to the disk, and that this contention for the disk IO is what is making each individual test slower. I tried to remedy this by writing the executable to a tmpfs location, but that barely made any difference. The write to this location is specified by the path I am passing in as a parameter to the function above,

Comment: I recommend `sudo perf record -ag` for the duration of your testing, and after killing it, analysis with `perf report`. You get a specific information in which functions time is spent, and if run as root (and if kernel debug symbols are available) even where in the kernel you wait.

Comment: Experience tells me compiler workloads are almost never limited by write performance. Especially on tmpfs, that should not be a factor – unless you're running out of RAM because you're making too heavy use of tmpfs, and things start to get swapped to disk.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've never used perf so I am a bit of a novice here. I did collect the graph, but the results confuse me a bit. The four biggest consumers seem to be a couple of calls to cc1 (symbols 0000000000000000, page_fault, entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe, do_syscall_64, in that order). These first four entries together account for 16.19% in the 'Children' column. What do you think I can conclude from this?

Comment: that 16.19% of times when perf sampled, the CPU was busy in `cc1`, which is the actual compiler. You don't have the debug symbols for GCC, so the symbol lookup is broken, but the fact that you're spending more time in `page_fault` than in syscalls means that the main non-compute time is not disk IO, but memory allocation, which you have little influence on.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hm I wonder how I can address this... increasing the size of my tmpfs storage affected nothing, and my program is given a pretty large heap (large enough that GC never runs). I mainly want to understand why these numbers are so different between the sequential program and parallel version.

Comment: My guess is it's really CPU and RAM contention. Do you have enough RAM?

Comment: @MarcusMüller htop reports 15.3G Mem, of which around 8.5G is used when I run the parallel tests. The Swp bar never increases when the tests are running.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have a new hunch that GCC is loading a lot of dependencies, and that this is what causes the latency? I include #stdio or something, and the preprocessor has to read this file (presumably stored on the disk).

Comment: But since things like stdio.h would be used by multiple processes, your in-memory disk caches would make that superlinearly faster, not slower.

Comment: Are you compiling something? Make sure you're using `-pipe` as a GCC/G++ flag.